# Laptop display lower resolution than monitors limit mouse motion

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, mouse, resolution

I have 2 new monitors with 2560 x 1440 resolution but my laptop has a maximum of 1920 x 1080 resolution. My display settings show the laptop screen as smaller than my displays. This causes my mouse to "hit" the edge of the larger monitors going to the small laptop screen when I am working. Other than reducing the resolution on my 2 monitors (I do cad work and need the high resolution) how can I increase the apparent size of my laptop screen so the settings think they are all the same size so my mouse cursor flows freely across all screens?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent of my knowledge, this is unfortunately not possible.

Screen arrangement in Windows 10 is done purely on a pixel basis, even if you select different scaling factors for different screens.

The only thing you can do is play with the screen position and for example align the laptop screen to the top edge or bottom edge of the other screens to control whether you can move the cursor to the laptop screen on the top or bottom 2/3 of the big screens.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Thanks.